# Copy constructor on return in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, return, copy-constructor

I'm trying to understand the following

```
#include <iostream>

class Number {
  int _value;
public:
  Number(int number) : _value(number) { std::cout<<"constructed!\n"; }
  Number(const Number& other) : _value(other._value) { std::cout<<"copied!\n"; }
  ~Number() { std::cout<<"destructed!\n"; }
};

Number create_number(int value) {
  Number out(value);
  return out;
}

int main() {
  Number my_number = create_number(10);
}
```

The output is

```
constructed!
destructed!
```

I would have expected that inside `create_number` an object would be constructed, copied to the output of the function and then destructed once the function returned.

Something like that seems to happen because if I make the copy constructor explicit

```
explicit Number(const Number& other) : _value(other._value) { std::cout<<"copied!\n"; }
```

the compiler yells on `return out` with `no matching constructor for initialization of 'Number'`. If I call the copy constructor within `create_number` explicitly or even cast the Number `out` to a Number (huh?)

```
return Number(out);
return (Number)out;
```

the compiler is happy and I get the expected output

```
constructed!
copied!
destructed!
destructed!
```

I feel like I'm missing something about `return`, copy constructors and/or (implicit) casting. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Look up "NRVO".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Without getting too much into the C++ standard's obscure language, in most cases the compiler *may* elide (optimize away) the copy, but isn't required to. This is treated like any other optimization.

Interestingly, this is a rare exception to the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), where the side-effects of an optimization are observable - see the notes in these links.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's finally time to read up on some topics I had been avoiding in the past.